# Disallow authors to edit/delete their own or other published posts

Tags: plugins

I would like to have people write on my blog and i am ok with editing their own posts while on draft. However, once their posts are published, I wouldn't like them to be able to edit/delete any published posts, not even the owned that they have written.

Is there a way to do that ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Downgrade tham to Contributors user role.

Comment: The contributor is not allowed to edit publish posts ? I thought they were allowed to edit their own ones.

Comment: thay have very limited capabilities... (edit_posts,read,level_1,level_0,delete_posts but no delete_published_posts and edit_published_posts as far as i can see.

Answer (score 1):

Add this code to your functions.php file or just use Snippet plugins to add it to your WP site. If you don't know about how to use this kind of code just search a bit.

```
function wpb_change_author_role(){
    global $wp_roles;
    $wp_roles->remove_cap( 'author', 'delete_posts' );
    $wp_roles->remove_cap( 'author', 'delete_published_posts' );
    $wp_roles->remove_cap( 'author', 'publish_posts' );
    $wp_roles->remove_cap( 'author', 'edit_published_posts' );
    #$wp_roles->remove_cap( 'author', 'edit_posts' );
}
add_action('init', 'wpb_change_author_role');
```